# Connecting with github via SSH return permission denied error

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm trying to connect via SSH however when trying this I keep on getting the error `Permission denied (public key)`. These were my steps:

```
make a key with ssh-keygen.
open ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub with Gedit or Notepad++ and copy the contents.
Go to account settings on github.com
Go to SSH Keys
Click on the Add Key button.
give the key a title
paste the key into the key box.
Save the key (enter my github password to verify).
```

When I execute ``` ssh-key -vT git@github.com`` I get the ``` Permission denied (public key)``` errror. Can anybody help me and tell me what's wrong? I applied the sampe procedure on another computer before and it worked.

Comment: Without logs or something more detailed, I have no idea where the mistake could be. However, I believe you should delete all of your SSH-KEYGEN files from Github and your PC (I would save them to a tmp folder anyhow) and restart the operation to see how things go, as something in your actions appears to have destroyed the entire pipe. Kindly contact us with additional information.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunatley I have tried to initiate a new SSH-KEYGEN multiple times. None of it worked. There seems to be some kind of connection since ``git reflog``` allows me to see my old history. Do you have any idea what else to do?